# Can someone use our session token and next useSession() hook to grab our decrypted session token?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

Slightly confused and not entirely sure if this is even possible. If someone performs a CSRF attack and hence have our cookies available (I understand they can't read them but get attached automatically), can they make a call to the nextjs useSession() and get a decrypted session token or does the useSession() hook verify the call using CSRF tokens? Can someone even call the useSession() hook by modifying the javascript code on a page?

Finally understood CSRF attacks and how CSRF tokens prevent them as well as how JWT tokens prevent XSS attacks but couldn't get my head around this one scenario.

Thanks!